# How to expire browser cache without server side scripting?

Tags: caching, browser

I have a website made with html, css and images.  My friends are seeing my website with an older version of css because their firefox browser cached the CSS.   I told some of them to clear the cache and it looked fine.

But some of my friends are not technologically savvy and don't know how to clear the cache.  Is there something I can put in my html code to force the website to expire the firefox browser cache if it is passed a certain date?

I do not have server side scripting abilities like perl, php, ruby etc...

If this is not possible, just say so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put Meta HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE" in your head tag
or I like META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT="Mon, 22 Jul 2002 11:12:01 GMT"